# Coding style for overloading operators

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, coding-style

Suppose that I have a class called `Rational` which represents rational numbers "purely", i.e it maintains the representation of a/b as `(a, b)` and implements the usual operators `+, -, *, /` and others to work on those tuples, instead of evaluating the actual fractions on every operation.

Suppose now that I want to define what happens if I add a `Rational` instance to an `Int`, in addition to the already defined behavior for `Rational` added to `Rational`. Then, of course, I might end up wanting to add `Rational` to `Double`, or to `Float`, `BigInt` other numeric types...

### Approach #1: Provide several implementations of `+(Rational, _)`:

```
def + (that:Rational):Rational  = {
    require(that != null, "Rational + Rational: Provided null argument.")
    new Rational(this.numer * that.denom + that.numer * this.denom, this.denom * that.denom)
}

def + (that:Int): Rational = this + new Rational(that, 1) // Constructor takes (numer, denom) pair

def + (that:BigInt): Rational = ....
.
.
.
```

### Approach #2: Pattern match on `Any`:

```
def + (that:Any):Rational  = {
    require(that != null, "+(Rational, Any): Provided null argument.")
    that match {
        case that:Rational => new Rational(this.numer * that.denom + that.numer * this.denom, this.denom * that.denom)
        case that:Int | BigInt => new Rational(this.numer + that * this.denom, this.denom) // a /b + c = (a + cb)/b
        case that:Double => ....
        .
        .
        .
        case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("+(Rational, Any): Unsupported operand.")
     }
}
```

One benefit I'm seeing from the pattern matching approach is saving in terms of actual source code lines, but perhaps with a decrease of readability. Perhaps more crucially, I have control over what I do when I'm provided with a type I haven't defined behavior of `+` for. I'm not certain how that could be attained via the first approach, perhaps by adding an overloading for `Any` underneath all the others? Either way, it sounds dangerous.

Ideas on whether one should opt for the first or second approach? Are there any safety issues I'm not seeing? Am I opening myself to `ClassCastException`s or other kinds of exceptions?

Comment: Why do you want to turn a perfectly fine compile time error into a runtime error? What should be the behavior of adding a type which is not supported, but simply refuse it at compile time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just to clarify, if the caller wanted to use my `Rational` instance to add it to an unsupported type, that is a compile-time error on their own front, yes?

Comment: yes, that would be the ideal situation on a statically typed language like **Scala**. Being said that, the best option would be the first one, or a third one using **typeclasses**. Now, if you also want to allow your users to extend your class, then **typeclasses** would be the best option. If not, maybe the first one is the best because of its simplicity.

Comment: I'm wondering: is there *any* way to *force* a compile-time error in this case *if* we were to follow approach #2?

Comment: Right now, there is no way that I am aware of. On a future in **Scala** `3.0` you could use **Union types** to achieve that. However, you can hack something a _sealed_ `ev` **typeclass**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to enforce a compile-time error is to ensure that the `plus` method cannot actually take type `Any`, via a type constraint, an implicit parameter, or the like.

One way of dealing with this would be to make use of the scala `Numeric` type class. It should be perfectly possible to create an instance for `Rational`, since you can easily implement all the required methods, and at that point you can define `plus` as

```
def +[T: Numeric](that: T) : Rational
```

You'd now also be able to pull out the `toInt`/`toLong`/`toFloat`/`toDouble` methods of the implicit `Numeric` argument to handle unknown classes instead of throwing a runtime error as well, if you wanted - and even if you don't, you've at least significantly cut down the erronous types that can be passed.

You could also define your own type class and appropriate instances of it for the types you want to support. Then you can either leave the addition logic in the `+` method or move it into the typeclass instances:

```
trait CanBeAdded[T] {
  def add(t: T, rational: Rational) : Rational
}

object CanBeAdded {
  implicit val int = new CanBeAdded[Int] {
    override def add(t: Int, rational: Rational): Rational = ???
  }

  implicit val long = new CanBeAdded[Long] {
    override def add(t: Long, rational: Rational): Rational = ???
  }

  implicit val rational = new CanBeAdded[Rational] {
    override def add(t: Rational, rational: Rational): Unit = ???
  }
}

case class Rational(a: BigInt, b: BigInt) {
  def +[T: CanBeAdded](that: T) = implicitly[CanBeAdded[T]].add(that, this)
}
```

I like the second option because I have to doubt that allowing your `Rational` type to be added to any numeric type makes sense. You mention that you want `+` to be able to take in `Double`s, but exact representation combined with the rounding errors that often crop up in `Double`s seems like it could lead to some very weird and counterintuitive behaviour with results that don't make much sense.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely, `Double`s were just an example. After all, you can approximate pi with a `Double`,  but that doesn't make the number `Rational`, now, does it. Only its approximation is `Rational`. Thank you very much. Clearly I have a lot of Scala studying to do.